# Problem with RadComboBox with ItemTemplate of asp:TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, itemtemplate, radcombobox

I am using a RadComboBox with an ItemTemplate that contains 50 TextBox controls that a user can enter information into. I add the 50 TextBox controls dynamically (see below). When information is entered into the textboxes, it appears that everything is working as expected. However, when I iterate the collection of TextBoxes, the data is not there. Here is my code:

aspx page:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="ddlListItemsQ1" runat="server" Width="200px" ShowDropDownOnTextboxClick="true" EnableEmbeddedSkins="false" Skin="Classic" TabIndex="2" ZIndex="100" disabled="true" OnClientDropDownOpening="OnDropdownListItemsOpening">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtBoxQ1" runat="server" Width="160"/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Load textboxes:

```
private void LoadDropdownListItems()
{
    int itemCount = 0;
    while (itemCount < 50)
    {
        ddlListItemsQ1.Items.Add(new RadComboBoxItem());
        itemCount++;
    }                
}
```

Examine collection:

```
RadComboBox ddlListItems = (RadComboBox)FindControl("ddlListItemsQ1");

IList<RadComboBoxItem> iList = ddlListItems.Items;
foreach (RadComboBoxItem rcbi in iList)
{
    if (rcbi.Text.Length > 0)
        return true;
}
```

Nothing is in any of the textboxes. For example, if I've entered text into 2 of the 50, I should get a "true" returned on the first one it comes across. When I debug and look at the collection - there is nothing stored in ANY of the textboxes even though in the UI, there are two with data. I must be missing something...

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is checking `rcbi.Text` but that is the Text of the `RadComboBoxItem`s that you added to the combo box....which is different than the text that is in the `TextBox` that you placed as part of the `ItemTemplate`.  Change your for loop to this and it should work:

```
IList<RadComboBoxItem> iList = ddlListItems.Items;
foreach (RadComboBoxItem rcbi in iList)
{
    //Find the inner textbox placed by the ItemTemplate
    var innerTextBox = (TextBox)rcbi.FindControl("txtBoxQ1");

    /Check the textbox's Text property
    if (innerTextBox.Text.Length > 0)
        return true;
}
```